# Cannot revert a file restored by svn up -rNNN

Tags: svn, github

I have a repository on Github and I use svn (1.8.5) to communicate with it. (I'm not sure it is important but it may be.)

There is a file, let's say `a.php` which is currently (say, in revision 1200) **not** in the repository but which used to be there (i.e. it was deleted in revision, say, 900).

So I wanted to have a look at the file and said like `svn up a.php -r899`, and I got the file. Then I needed to restore the normal trunk, so I tried `svn up`, `svn up a.php` and `svn up a.php -r1200` but none of them worked. So I still have the file in the local copy, and it doesn't show in `svn status` as if it were in the repository, but it apparently is not, since if I try to change (incl. delete) and commit it, I get an error:

`svn: E175002: PUT request on '<here was the path>' failed: 500 Internal Server Error`

Any ideas?

**Upd.** The issue can be reproduced the following way:

```
svn co https://github.com/OpenCorpora/opencorpora/trunk
cd trunk/ajax
svn up dict_reload.php -r1501
```

Comment: Did you try to delete the file and simply do an svn up? Instead of commit? What does svn stat give you?

Comment: I did, it gets restored. svn stat gives nothing.

Comment: 1. You **have** dict_reload.php in HEAD (2061) 2. You selected The Bad Way (tm) of inspecting old content of repo: `svn cat URL/FILE@PEG-REV > file` do the trick better 3. GitHub's SVN isn't clean use-case - it's Git repo behind the scene

Comment: At the moment of posting the initial question it was not in the HEAD, I committed it later.

Answer (score 1):

This is really GitHub-effect. For **pure SVN** (recommended way) I got for local test-case in such repository

```
>svn log -q -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r6 | Badger | 2014-09-26 03:36:26 +0600 (Пт, 26 сен 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/b.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r5 | Badger | 2014-09-26 03:35:56 +0600 (Пт, 26 сен 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/a.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | Badger | 2014-09-26 03:35:29 +0600 (Пт, 26 сен 2014)
Changed paths:
   D /trunk/c.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2014-09-26 03:34:39 +0600 (Пт, 26 сен 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/a.txt
   M /trunk/b.txt
   M /trunk/c.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | Badger | 2014-09-26 03:33:40 +0600 (Пт, 26 сен 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/a.txt
   A /trunk/b.txt
   A /trunk/c.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | Badger | 2014-09-26 03:31:52 +0600 (Пт, 26 сен 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /branches
   A /tags
   A /trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(c.txt deleted in r4, from WC in HEAD I want /by your way/ to see r3) following **expected results**

```
>svn up c.txt -r 3
Updating 'c.txt':
A    c.txt
Updated to revision 3.

>svn up
Updating '.':
D    c.txt
Updated to revision 6.
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've found an unobvious way to overcome the issue. Let's say the revision in which the file was deleted is 1502.

```
rm a.php
svn up a.php -r1500
svn up a.php -r1502
```

This way it gets deleted.